# Merge form fields into one using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I'm a non-programming designer trying to help out a friend and could use a little help with javascript.  I have a form which will populate a shopping cart.  That form has multiple fields (text fields, radio buttons) all of which have validation; this much I think I've got down.  One field (size) has hidden fields which are used to populate a shopping cart with the size, default quantity, and price.  That all works just fine.

Here is my problem.  I need to take the values from the rest of the form fields and get them to populate that same shopping cart field.  I assume the way to do this is by combining or merging the other forms fields into one, that being  in my form.

Is there a script that would accomplish this?  Can you offer any advice?

The form can be found here http://www.words-onthewall.com/testform2.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand which fields are "_the rest of the form fields_" and which field is "_that same shopping cart field_".  Could you explain?

Comment: Do you have another form that can successfully submit those values to that page? That form is submitting to a cfm script, which will only accept certain query parameters.

Comment: Hjahroy, the form field "size" currently populates a shopping cart by providing the plaque size and price.  I need to know if I can use javascript to take the other form fields - color, finish, font, words, source, layout - and merge those on submit with that of "size" into a string which will then populate the shopping cart.

Alex, the form which currently populates the cart is at http://www.words-onthewall.com/create-inspiration.html  Problem here is that the form sends a string with all the options to the cart as a separate line item with all option's having the name="product1[]".